# How to avoid having to write namespace before class C#

Tags: c#, using

So I made a .dll which I added to my project everything works, but when I try to use any of the class from my .dll. I have to specificly use namespace.classname instead of being able to just say Classname even when I put at the top of my project

> using namespace

```
using System;
using MyTestClassLibrary;
using System.IO;
using YangHandler;

namespace UsingMyclassdll
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            YangHandler.YangHandler yangh = YangHandler.YangHandler.Parse("Rawtext");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

At the line of using Yanghandler visual studio says

> Using directive is unnecessary

Isn't this what using is exactly used for to use other namespaces?

> YangHandler code

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace YangHandler
{
    public class YangHandler
    {
        public string YangAsRawText { get; private set; }

        public static YangHandler Parse(string YangAsRawText)
        {
            YangHandler handlerToReturn = new YangHandler();

            handlerToReturn.YangAsRawText = YangAsRawText;

            return handlerToReturn;
        }
```

I know that it could be solved by using namespace aliases under the namespace "UsingMyclassdll" like

> using YangHandler = YangHandler.YangHandler;

But isn't there a more normal solution?

Comment: using namespace name = class name is bad practice.

Comment: Remove `using YangHandler;` or `YangHandler.`? Or change the name of the `YangHandler` class or the `YangHandler` namespace.

Comment: Why would you do that? The normal solution is to use the namespace...

Comment: Do not have a namespace with the same name as your class. Then you can utilize the `using` structure.

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one

Comment: @lordvlad30 I renamed and it worked I think you said it first if you make an actual answer I can check it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this very interesting piece of documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces

> DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.
>
> For example, do not use Debug as a namespace name and then also provide a class named Debug in the same namespace. Several compilers require such types to be fully qualified.

So your work around is basically defining the fully qualified name as the type and namespace are of the same name.

No work around for this. The compiler can't know if you mean the one or the other.